# Как по списку значений найти вхождение этих значений в строки в датафрейме?

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.5, dataframe

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать? Есть фрейм со списком названий товаров и есть список значений, которые в некоторых случаях входят частично в названия товара. Как определить эти значения? Пример:

Фрейм:

```
    Item
0   Товар один
1   Товар два
2   Товар три
3   Товар четыре
4   Товар пять
5   Товар шесть
6   Товар семь
7   Товар восемь
8   Товар девять
9   Товар десять
```

список искомых значений:

```
to_find = ['два', 'четыре', 'шесть']
```

Пытаюсь получить серию, где будет True и False в случае вхождения и невхождения, соответственно. Пробовал такие варианты:

```
1. exp['Item'].str.contains(to_find)
```

Получаю ошибку "unhashable type: 'list'"

```
2. exp['Item'].isin(to_find)
```

Получаю обратно только False

```
3. Пробовал сцеплять условия:
mask = (exp['Item'].str.contains('два')) & (exp['Item'].str.contains('четыре'))
exp['New'] = np.where(mask, True, False)
```

Результат:

```
    Item    New
0   Товар один  False
1   Товар два   False
2   Товар три   False
3   Товар четыре    False
4   Товар пять  False
5   Товар шесть False
6   Товар семь  False
7   Товар восемь    False
8   Товар девять    False
9   Товар десять    False
```

Comment: интересно, а если `to_find = {'два', 'четыре', 'шесть'}`. А можете приложить к вопросу заполненный `exp`? Чтобы сразу можно было скопировать и поиграться, а то заполнять желания нет :)

Comment: @gil9red, Фрейм в самом верху и есть exp)

Comment: ну, хотелось бы именно в коде, чтобы Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V и запустить :)

Comment: @gil9red, `df = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\s{2,}', index_col=0)` в буфере выделенный DataFrame из вопроса (как есть) ;)

Comment: @MaxU, блин, в этом модуле все сделано для людей :)

Comment: @gil9red, да, пока хватает памяти (RAM) - это пожалуй один из самых продвинутых модулей для обработки табличных данных

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Series.str.contains()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) ожидает регулярное выражение на вход:

```
In [39]: pat = r'\b(?:{})\b'.format('|'.join(to_find))

In [40]: pat
Out[40]: '\\b(?:два|четыре|шесть)\\b'

In [41]: df['Item'].str.contains(pat)
Out[41]:
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
5     True
6    False
7    False
8    False
9    False
Name: Item, dtype: bool
```

---

ещё один вариант - разбить `Item` на слова, т.е. преобразовать один столбец в DataFrame, с одним словом в каждом столбце и использовать [DataFrame.isin()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html):

```
In [45]: df['Item'].str.split(expand=True).isin(to_find).any(axis=1)
Out[45]:
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
5     True
6    False
7    False
8    False
9    False
dtype: bool
```

пошагово:

```
In [46]: df['Item'].str.split(expand=True)
Out[46]:
       0       1
0  Товар    один
1  Товар     два
2  Товар     три
3  Товар  четыре
4  Товар    пять
5  Товар   шесть
6  Товар    семь
7  Товар  восемь
8  Товар  девять
9  Товар  десять

In [47]: df['Item'].str.split(expand=True).isin(to_find)
Out[47]:
       0      1
0  False  False
1  False   True
2  False  False
3  False   True
4  False  False
5  False   True
6  False  False
7  False  False
8  False  False
9  False  False
```

Comment: спасибо! А решение с передачей списка или множества в качестве аргумента не существует?

Comment: @DenisNovik, добавил вариант, в котором не надо преобразовывать список...

Comment: спасибо вам большое! Вы круче google по владению pandas. Только здесь ответы нахожу)

Comment: @DenisNovik, рад что мои знания могут оказаться полезными кому-нибудь ещё  :)